# NativeScript Class.getClass cannot identify the unidentified class: <Buffer@0x0 > pointer: 0

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

When I run: `tns run ios --emulator` I get:

```
Class.getClass cannot identify the unidentified class:  <Buffer@0x0 >  pointer: 0
```

All I have done is git clone'd the example repository [sample-Groceries](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries.git) and run add platform for android and ios, nothing else.

I am running xcode 5, I can get the emulator running via IOS emulator. When I run again `tns run ios --emulator` when IOS emulator is open i get:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileStoryboard sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard
(1 failure)
Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
```

Below is the whole output:

```
Project successfully prepared
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.4
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = "i386"

=== BUILD TARGET sampleGroceries OF PROJECT sampleGroceries WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution NativeScript\ PreBuild build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Script-C97FD7AC1ADE5369004DB2A4.sh
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Script-C97FD7AC1ADE5369004DB2A4.sh
~/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal/metadata-generator/bin ~/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
Generating metadata for i386
Metadata Generator Arguments:
"./objc-metadata-generator", "-output-bin", "/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/metadata-i386.bin", "-output-umbrella", "/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/umbrella-i386.h", "-docset-path", "/Users/magan/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset", "Xclang", "-isysroot", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk", "-arch", "i386", "-miphoneos-version-min=8.0", "-target", "arm-apple-darwin", "-std=gnu99", "-I/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/include", "-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include", "-I/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal/", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/../../lib/iOS", "-F../../lib/iOS", "-DDEBUG=1",
Clang Arguments:
"-v", "-x", "objective-c", "-fno-objc-arc", "-fmodule-maps", "-ferror-limit=0", "-Wno-unknown-pragmas", "-Wno-ignored-attributes", "-isysroot", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk", "-arch", "i386", "-miphoneos-version-min=8.0", "-target", "arm-apple-darwin", "-std=gnu99", "-I/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/include", "-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include", "-I/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal/", "-F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/../../lib/iOS", "-F../../lib/iOS", "-DDEBUG=1",
Merged 400 categories.
Result: 23690 declarations from 79 top level modules
Done! Running time: 10.0993 sec
~/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios

Ld build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/sampleGroceries normal i386
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator -F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator -F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal -F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/../../lib/iOS -F../../lib/iOS -filelist /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Objects-normal/i386/sampleGroceries.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -sectcreate __DATA __TNSMetadata /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/metadata-i386.bin -framework NativeScript -F/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/internal -licucore -lz -lc++ -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework TNSWidgets -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Objects-normal/i386/sampleGroceries_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/sampleGroceries

PhaseScriptExecution NativeScript\ PreLink build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Script-CD62955B1BB2651D00AE3A93.sh
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/Script-CD62955B1BB2651D00AE3A93.sh

CpResource sampleGroceries/app build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/app
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/app /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app

CpResource sampleGroceries/Resources/build.xcconfig build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/build.xcconfig
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/build.xcconfig /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app

CompileStoryboard sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --errors --warnings --notices --module sampleGroceries --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/LaunchScreen-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.errors */
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard:SX8-MR-1I8: error: Launch screens may not use instances of IBUIStoryboardEntryPointIndicator.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard:SX8-MR-1I8: error: Launch screens may only have one top level object, which must be a UIView or a kind of UIViewController.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard:uJw-wh-q4r: error: Launch screens may not use instances of IBUISceneExitPlaceholder.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard:uJw-wh-q4r: error: Launch screens may only have one top level object, which must be a UIView or a kind of UIViewController.

CpResource sampleGroceries/Resources/logo.png build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/logo.png
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/logo.png /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app

CpResource sampleGroceries/Resources/logo@2x.png build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/logo@2x.png
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/logo@2x.png /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app

CpResource sampleGroceries/Resources/logo@3x.png build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/logo@3x.png
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/logo@3x.png /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app

CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets
    cd /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/assetcatalog_dependencies.txt --output-partial-info-plist /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --platform iphonesimulator --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --compress-pngs --compile /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app /Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets
2016-07-03 08:41:12.581 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[2724:35493] CoreUI(DEBUG): CSIGenerator using LZVN Compression coreui version (307.300000)
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][][][][][Icon-60@3x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 3 unassigned images.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[iphone][60x60][][][3x]: warning: The file "icon-60@3x.png" for the image set "AppIcon" does not exist.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[iphone][57x57][][][1x]: notice: 57x57 app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[iphone][57x57][][][2x]: notice: 57x57@2x app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][50x50][][][1x]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][50x50][][][2x]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][72x72][][][1x]: notice: 72x72 app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][72x72][][][2x]: notice: 72x72@2x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][736h][3x][portrait][full-screen][8.0]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][736h][3x][landscape][full-screen][8.0]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][667h][2x][portrait][full-screen][8.0]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][][1x][portrait][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][][2x][portrait][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][retina4][2x][portrait][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[ipad][][1x][portrait][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[ipad][][1x][landscape][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[ipad][][2x][portrait][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/sampleGroceries/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[ipad][][2x][landscape][full-screen][]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon29x29.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon57x57.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon57x57@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon50x50~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon50x50@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon72x72~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon72x72@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-800-Landscape-736h@3x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-568h@2x.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-Portrait~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-Landscape~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app/Assets.car
/Users/magan/MEGAsync/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/sampleGroceries.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleGroceries.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

Comment: This was solved by upgrading to xcode 7.